# Datatables.js bootstrap breaks modal form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Im using Datatables to generate table with button which opens modal window on click. But my modal form looks broken like this:

[image]

But without DT looks like I wanted to:

[image]

Im using DataTables just like that:

```
var table = $('#productsAdminTable')
table.DataTable({});
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: It sounds rather impossible. If you look at the [**dataTables bootstrap CSS**](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css) all selectors is targeting specific "dataTables-centric" class names.  So perhaps you are by accident using a class with the same name as one of those?

Comment: Im using React Bootstrap. Is does matter? Maybe it's impossible but when I start to use Footable.js problem dissapear.